# Python statically typed constructor?

Tags: python, datetime, constructor

first of all, I'm brand new to python, and have basic understanding of c/c++/c# which are all statically typed languages. So can the following be done in python?

I want the variable birthday to be a datetime. So that whenever I instantiate I have to pass a datetime in with the parameters.

```
import datetime

class Person:
    """class representing a person."""

    def __init__(self, name, sirname, gender, birthday):
        self.name = name
        self.sirname = sirname
        self.gender = gender
        self.birthday = datetime.date(birthday)

    def getage(self):
        """returns age"""
        today = datetime.date.today()
        return today.year - self.birthday.year
```

Further down I instantiate as following

```
BIRTHDAY = datetime.date(1989, 10, 9)
NIELSON = Person('Nielson', 'Jansen', 'Male', BIRTHDAY)
```

this gives me the error:
*TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)*

is my instantiate wrong or should i get the following out of my head asap with python?

```
self.birthday = datetime.date(birthday)
```

(Why I would like to do this is so that the *getage* method always is presented with a datetime.date instead of something random if I make an instantiate mistake.)

PS: also, if my terminology is not correct, don’t hesitate to correct me. :)

Comment: If you're already passing in a `datetime`, why are you then trying to convert it to a `datetime`? See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) - if you pass a single argument, it's expected to be a year.

Comment: Python doesn't have static-type checking. You are seeing *runtime* type-checking, which is occuring because you are passing an argument of the wrong type to `datetime.date`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you fix

```
self.birthday = datetime.date(birthday)
```

into

```
self.birthday = birthday
```

as [suggested by jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837568/python-statically-typed-constructor#comment80622774_46837568).

Now if you want to check the type of birthday, you can write

```
assert isinstance(birthday, datetime.date)
```

at the beginning of the constructor. This is however not a static check because the check will only be performed when the assertion will run.